# Error when replacing characters applescript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, sh, executable-jar

I am trying to make a script that executes a runnable Jar file in the form of an applescript application. I'm not very experienced in applescript, so I mostly went off of online snippets. The first problem I ran into was that the directory automatically formats as using a ":" instead of a slash (ex. "usr:bin" instead of "usr/bin") so I found something that's supposed to replace the : with a /. This, however, produces an error every time.

I've found little on how to fix my error and the stuff I found was very specific to those cases and didn't make much sense to me.

This is my code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set current_path to container of (path to me) as alias
end tell

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
set currPath to text items of current_path
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
set current_path to currPath as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
currPath

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set currentTab to do script ("cd " & current_path)
    set currentTab to do script ("java -jar Inoisulcnoc Pre-Alpha 2")
end tell
```

The error I get every time says:

**error** "Can’t get every text item of alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:knotsnappy:Desktop:Inoisulcnoc Pre-Alpha 2:\"." number -1728 from **every** *text item* of *alias* "Macintosh HD:Users:knotsnappy:Desktop:Inoisulcnoc Pre-Alpha 2:"

How should I be able to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to change the standard path into a `POSIX` path.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set current_path to (POSIX path of (container of (path to me) as alias))
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set currentTab to do script ("cd " & current_path)
    set currentTab to do script ("java -jar Inoisulcnoc Pre-Alpha 2")
end tell
```

The delimiters, etc. are unneeded once you have the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that problem entirely. the only problem I ran into now is that that doesn't account for if the directory has spaces, so if the user puts it in a folder named "Inoisulcnoc Program" for example it will only look for a folder called "Inoisulcnoc." I know that wasn't my original question, but do you by any chance have a solution for this?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed everything with:

tell application "Finder"
 set current_path to (POSIX path of (container of (path to me) as alias))
end tell

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
set currPath to text items of current_path
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\\ "
set current_path to currPath as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
currPath

tell application "Terminal"
 activate
 set currentTab to do script ("cd " & current_path & "; java -jar " & current_path & "Inoisulcnoc.jar")
end tell

Comment: You’re welcome! To accommodate paths that might have spaces use `& quoted form of current_path`.